# append the exiting json data in python and write the updated file back to json

Tags: python, json

i have a json file which contains users array with 3 objects which i created while setting up my json file. I want to read the the data in my python script and afterwards i want to save new user objects in my json file under the users array. I tried appending the data but it only appended for the dictionary and didnot update my json file. Can anyone help?

This is my json file:

```
    {
"data":[
 {      
     "name":"greetings",
     "question":["hey","hi","hello"],
     "patterns":["hi","hey","hello"]
 },
 {
    "name":"start",
    "question":["how are you","how was your day","how are you doing"],
    "patterns":["Am great","it was great","Great!!"]
 },
 {  
    "name":"name", 
    "question":["what is your name","name please?"],
    "patterns":["My name is Elle, How may I help you"]
 }, 
 {
    "name":"menu", 
    "question":["whats in the menu","Can you please provide me with the menu "],
    "patterns":[
        {
            "starters":["cheese balls","chicken corn soup","mozrella sticks","prawn crisps"],
            "maincourse":["bar-b-q pizza","chicken burger","chowmin"],
            "deserts":["chocolate cake","apple pie","cake alaska","strawaberry icecream"]
        }
    ]
 },
 {  
    "name":"choice",
    "question":[],
    "pattern":["here you go enjoy your meal"]
 }
],
"users":[
    {     
      "userid":1,
      "username":"faheel sattar",
      "preference":""     
    },
    {     
        "userid":1,
        "username":"faheel sattar",
        "preference":""     
    },
    {     
        "userid":1,
        "username":"faheel sattar",
        "preference":""     
    } 
]
    }
```

This is my python script:

```
    import json
    import numpy as np
    with open('lab3/data.json') as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      print(data["users"])
    users={
     "userid":4,
     "username":"fahdsdsdl sattar",
     "preference":",sdsd"
    }
    data["users"].append(users)
    data.update(data)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f: 
      json.dump(data["users"],f)
      print(data["users"])
```

what i want in my json as output look at the last user object that just got added in users arrary with "userid":4 :

```
    {
    data":[
    {      
     "name":"greetings",
     "question":["hey","hi","hello"],
     "patterns":["hi","hey","hello"]
    },
    {
     "name":"start",
     "question":["how are you","how was your day","how are you doing"],
     "patterns":["Am great","it was great","Great!!"]
    },
    {  
     "name":"name", 
     "question":["what is your name","name please?"],
     "patterns":["My name is Elle, How may I help you"]
    }, 
    {
     "name":"menu", 
     "question":["whats in the menu","Can you please provide me with the 
     menu "],
    "patterns":[
        {
            "starters":["cheese balls","chicken corn soup","mozrella 
             sticks","prawn crisps"],
            "maincourse":["bar-b-q pizza","chicken burger","chowmin"],
            "deserts":["chocolate cake","apple pie","cake 
             alaska","strawaberry icecream"]
        }
    ]
 },
 {  
    "name":"choice",
    "question":[],
    "pattern":["here you go enjoy your meal"]
 }
],
"users":[
    {     
      "userid":1,
      "username":"faheel sattar",
      "preference":""     
    },
    {     
        "userid":1,
        "username":"faheel sattar",
        "preference":""     
    },
    {     
        "userid":1,
        "username":"faheel sattar",
        "preference":""     
    },
    {     
        "userid":4,
        "username":"fahdsdsdl sattar",
        "preference":",sdsd"     
    } 

]
    }
```

Comment: You are just writing the `data['users']` to the file. Either you can write the whole `data` variable to the file or you can open the file in append mode using `with open('data.json', 'a') as f:` then write the `data['users']`

Comment: @techytushar its still not working with 'a'

Comment: Just write the whole `data` to the file using `json.dump(data,f)`

Comment: @techytushar yes i tried it but Its not working

Comment: Please post what you want in your output file (edit the post)?

Comment: with open('data.json', 'w') as f: 
        json.dump(data,f)
        print(data["users"])